# Unicode in javadoc and comments?

Tags: java, unicode, comments, javadoc

Some compilers failed on non-ASCII characters in JavaDoc and source code comments. What is the current (Java 7) and future (Java 8 and beyond) practices with respect to Unicode in Java source files? Are there differences between IcedTea, OpenJDK, and other Java environments, and what is dictated the the language specification? Should all non-ASCII characters be escaped in JavaDoc with HTML *&escape;*-like codes? But what would be the Java *// comment* equivalent?

**Update**: comments indicate that one can use any character set, and that upon compiling one needs to indicate what char set is used in the source file. I will look into this, and will be looking for details on how to configure this via Ant, Eclipse, and Maven.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Syntax/Unicode_Source) (I'm certain this is specified by JLS).

Comment: Actually, you can use any encoding you want in your source files, you just need to indicate which one you chose to the Java compiler and the javadoc command-line.

Comment: OK, this is the kind of information I am looking for! First, this is very cool, and was not aware of this. So, now I just need to figure out how to get the compiler to know what char set to use... for example, the CDK is compiled using Ant, Maven, and Eclipse...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Some compilers failed on non-ASCII characters in JavaDoc and source code comments.

This is likely because the compiler assumes that the input is UTF-8, and there are invalid UTF-8 sequences in the source file.  That these appear to be in comments in your source code editor is irrelevant because the lexer (which distinguishes comments from other tokens) never gets to run.  The failure occurs while the tool is trying to convert bytes into chars before the lexer runs.

---

The `man` page for `javac` and `javadoc` say

```
-encoding name
          Specifies  the  source  file  encoding   name,   such   as
          EUCJIS/SJIS.   If  this option is not specified, the plat-
          form default converter is used.
```

so running `javadoc` with the encoding flag

```
javadoc -encoding <encoding-name> ...
```

after replacing `<encoding-name>` with the encoding you've used for your source files should cause it to use the right encoding.

If you've got more than one encoding used within a group of source files that you need to compile together, you need to fix that first and settle on a single uniform encoding for all source files.  You should really just use UTF-8 or stick to ASCII.

---

> What is the current (Java 7) and future (Java 8 and beyond) practices with respect to Unicode in Java source files?

The algorithm for dealing with a source file in Java is

1. Collect bytes
2. Convert bytes to chars (UTF-16 code units) using some encoding.
3. Replace all sequences of `'\\'` `'u'` followed by four hex digits with the code-unit corresponding to those hex-digits.  Error out if there is a `"\u"` not followed by four hex digits.
4. Lex the chars into tokens.
5. Parse the tokens into classes.

The current and former practice is that step 2, converting bytes to UTF-16 code units, is up to the tool that is loading the compilation unit (source file) but the de facto standard for command line interfaces is to use the `-encoding` flag.

After that conversion happens, the language mandates that `\uABCD` style sequences are converted to UTF-16 code units (step 3) before lexing and parsing.

For example:

```
int a;
\u0061 = 42;
```

is a valid pair of Java statements.
Any java source code tool must, after converting bytes to chars but before parsing, look for \uABCD sequences and convert them so this code is converted to

```
int a;
a = 42;
```

before parsing.  This happens regardless of where the \uABCD sequence occurs.

This process looks something like

1. Get bytes: `[105, 110, 116, 32, 97, 59, 10, 92, 117, 48, 48, 54, 49, 32, 61, 32, 52, 50, 59]`
2. Convert bytes to chars: `['i', 'n', 't', ' ', 'a', ';', '\n', '\\', 'u', '0', '0', '6', '1', ' ', '=', ' ', '4', '2', ';']`
3. Replace unicode escapes: `['i', 'n', 't', ' ', 'a', ';', '\n', a, ' ', '=', ' ', '4', '2', ';']`
4. Lex: `["int", "a", ";", "a", "=", "42", ";"]`
5. Parse: `(Block (Variable (Type int) (Identifier "a")) (Assign (Reference "a") (Int 42)))`

---

> Should all non-ASCII characters be escaped in JavaDoc with HTML &escape;-like codes?

No need except for HTML special characters like `'<'` that you want to appear literally in the documentation.  You can use `\uABCD` sequences inside javadoc comments.
Java process `\u....` before parsing the source file so they can appear inside strings, comments, anywhere really.  That's why

```
System.out.println("Hello, world!\u0022);
```

is a valid Java statement.

```
/** @return \u03b8 in radians */
```

is equivalent to

```
/** @return θ in radians */
```

as far as javadoc is concerned.

---

> But what would be the Java `//` comment equivalent?

You can use `//` comments in java but Javadoc only looks inside `/**...*/` comments for documentation.  `//` comments are not metadata carrying.

One ramification of Java's handling of `\uABCD` sequences is that although

```
// Comment text.\u000A System.out.println("Not really comment text");
```

looks like a single line comment, and many IDEs will highlight it as such, it is not.

Comment: Will the java tools respect emacs/vim metadata about encoding?

Comment: @Marcin, if you mean a comment like `// -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` at the start of the file, a tool could elect to do so, but the Sun tools do not AFAIK.

Comment: @Marcin, yeah.  Source code encoding is a PITA.  A lot of newer languages are mandating or strongly suggest UTF-8 as the encoding format for their source files.  [JSON](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) and [Python](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html) default "The default encoding is UTF-8", "defaults to UTF-8".  [Go](http://golang.org/ref/spec) and [Rust](http://doc.rust-lang.org/doc/rust.html) are stricter: "Source code is Unicode text encoded in UTF-8", "input is interpreted as a sequence of Unicode codepoints encoded in UTF-8."  Java should for `-source 1.7`.

Answer (score 5):

As commenters indicated, the encoding of the source files can be passed to (at least some) compilers. In this answer, I will summarize how to pass this information.

**Eclipse**

Eclipse (3.7 checked) does not require any special configuration, and you can happily use Java source code like:

```
double π = Math.PI;
```

**Ant**

```
<javac encoding="UTF-8" ... >
</javac>
```

**Java**

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 src/main/Foo.java
```

**Gradle**

```
javadoc {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```