# Eclipse - Generate JavaDoc - NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, javadoc

I haven't generated JavaDocs for the Android project I've been working on for about a month. I just tried, and I'm getting the following output (with no output to my output directory):

```
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:83)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:44)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl.superclassType(ClassDocImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.getAllInterfaces(Util.java:447)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.getAllInterfaces(Util.java:485)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.processType(ClassTree.java:184)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.buildTree(ClassTree.java:136)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.<init>(ClassTree.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:123)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:83)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
2016 warnings
```

I'm building the docs at the project level (Android), and am include ActionBarSherlock and Facebook's Android project. Regardless of if I include them though, the documentation still fails.

I'm attempting to run this in Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Indigo, Build 20120216-1857

The JavaDoc command is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javadoc
```

Playing with the configuration a bit, and I'm getting the following error:

`full/path/BaseModelListAdapter.java:147: error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
   * @param parent?`

The line which is:

`* @param parentß`

Removing that line removes one of the errors, but I'm still getting weird ones, like the inability to find the base Android packages:

`/full/path/CompositeCategoryAdapter.java:7: error: package android.view does not exist
import android.view.View;
                   ^`

And symbol errors:

```
BaseModelListAdapter.java:420: error: cannot find symbol
public static BaseModelItemRowViewHolder createInstance( View v )
                                                         ^
symbol:   class View
location: class BaseModelItemRowViewHolder
```

Comment: You're really asking two questions here: one is the NPE you're getting, and the other appears to be an unrelated classpath issue.  Try creating a new question for the classpath issue, and you may get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to run:

```
javadoc -encoding utf-8
```

Alternatively, you can just use Unicode escapes (e.g. `\u0000`) instead of including Unicode characters directly.

Possibly related question: [Unicode in javadoc and comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363188/unicode-in-javadoc-and-comments)

Comment: Good call, but it seems that symbol was the only cause of the error, so removing it fixed that particular issue. I'm still having tons of symbol and package errors popup.

Comment: @Josh: Is your *entire* codebase using the same encoding?  My guess is that the compiler is getting tripped up by encoding issues somewhere else.  If after you fix all the encoding errors, you still have issues, then you might want to open a new question for those.

Comment: I don't think it was really an ecoding issue to begin with, as removing that character (and applying your argument) both removed only the single issue that was happening. As noted in my edits, as I've been working with this, I've found the two dominent errors to be of symbol and package reference in nature.