# \u in Java comment is leading to error message, why?

Tags: java, unicode

```
// \u represent unicode sequence
    char c = '\u0045';
    System.out.println(c);
```

Code is only this much and eclipse is showing following error message

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Invalid unicode
```

Now when I remove `\u` from comment it is working fine, what is the problem with `\u` in comment? IS this a bug or there is some relation, as far as  think Java should leave the comments as it is.

Comment: \ is an escape sequence in Java. it has a special meaning for the compiler.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: IntelliJ does not show any error if I add `\u` in a comment, I think is a Eclipse compiler issue

Comment: @Stultuske, but if I put only '\' there it work fine the problem is coming only with '\u'. Deepak Yea I was also thinking it should work. Pablo, it should not be the eclipse issue only as if I ignore the error and proceed compiler is giving error message but you are saying it is working with IntelliJ, it is strange.

Comment: well ... you use something in two different ways .... yes, it's normal that that can trigger two different results

Comment: @PabloLozano doesn't compile with javac either - IntelliJ is using relaxed rules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compiler will read your entire source code first (the comment will be ignored later), but he can't recognize "\u ", because it is no valid unicode-character.

To fix it, you can write

```
// \\u represent unicode sequence (extra backslash for escaping)
```

or

```
// \ u represent unicode sequence (extra whitespace for escaping)
```

**Edit:**
This is because the compiler translates everything into unicode first. Writing this simple programm

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // \u000A System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

outputs **Hi**, because `\u000A` stands for newline. [Proof](http://ideone.com/fork/YmwzWl)

Comment: That is annoying, I had path with `...\upload\...` in the comments and got the error message, so you even have to escape your comments !

Answer (score 5):

The comments are interpreted as well to some degree. 
A short research has yielded the following result to your question:
[Unicode in javadoc and comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363188/unicode-in-javadoc-and-comments)